# Change date of a DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file named `data.csv` such as

```
TS;val
10:00;0.1
10:05;0.2
10:10;0.3
10:15;0.4
```

I read this csv file using this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    yyyy = 2013
    mm = 2
    dd = 1

    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)

    print(df)
```

I get this

```
                     val
TS                      
2013-06-17 10:00:00  0.1
2013-06-17 10:05:00  0.2
2013-06-17 10:10:00  0.3
2013-06-17 10:15:00  0.4
```

I would like to change date of every DateTimeIndex to 2013-02-01

```
                     val
TS                      
2013-02-01 10:00:00  0.1
2013-02-01 10:05:00  0.2
2013-02-01 10:10:00  0.3
2013-02-01 10:15:00  0.4
```

What is the easier way to do this ?

Comment: you can use `datetime.replace(year, month, day)` on the dates

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Timestamps have a `replace` method (just like datetimes):

```
In [11]: df.index.map(lambda t: t.replace(year=2013, month=2, day=1))
Out[11]:
array([Timestamp('2013-02-01 10:00:00', tz=None),
       Timestamp('2013-02-01 10:05:00', tz=None),
       Timestamp('2013-02-01 10:10:00', tz=None),
       Timestamp('2013-02-01 10:15:00', tz=None)], dtype=object)
```

So set your index to this:

```
In [12]: df.index = df.index.map(lambda t: t.replace(year=2013, month=2, day=1))
```

Worth mentioning that you can pass in a `date_parser` function to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), which might make more sense for you:

```
In [21]: df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=';', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, 
                          date_parser=lambda time: pd.Timestamp('2013/02/01 %s' % time))

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
                     val
TS
2013-02-01 10:00:00  0.1
2013-02-01 10:05:00  0.2
2013-02-01 10:10:00  0.3
2013-02-01 10:15:00  0.4
```

Comment: a slightly different way than Andy's answer: ``df.index = [ Timestamp('20130201') + timedelta(hours=t.hour,minutes=t.minute) for t in df.index.time ]``

Comment: It works fine but I wonder if it will be more efficient to use read_csv with differents parameters. Because read_csv set date to today and we replace date... maybe we could do this using only one step ?

Comment: @AndyHayden TOTD, I just posted same :(

Comment: this gives ``TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments``

Comment: @muon this works when entries are timestamps or datetime (where the replace method accepts the above kwargs). If it's a string, you'll see the error you describe.

Comment: Thanks @AndyHayden, I  got it working by converting to datetime, forgot to update comment :(

Answer (score 1):

provide a `date_parser`

```
In [50]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=';', parse_dates=[0], 
                     index_col=0, date_parser=lambda x: Timestamp('20130201 %s' % x))
Out[50]: 
                     val
TS                      
2013-02-01 10:00:00  0.1
2013-02-01 10:05:00  0.2
2013-02-01 10:10:00  0.3
2013-02-01 10:15:00  0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing this. The first one being the simplest: Use `'string'.split(' ')`. For the string `bb jj`, it will return a list of 2 elements `bb` and `jj`, so just get the first element.

The second option, is to create a datetime object from the string, and reformat it the way you want. This solution is better in my opinion. If tomorrow you want another format, this will be much easier.
To do so: use the `strptime` function documented here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Then to return a string from a datetime object, simply use the [strftime function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). All the different format are available here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior