# Change only the date value in datetime column index

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I have a dataframe with data per second the original format of that data is '%H:%M:%S'; however, when I put pd.to_datetime, automatically a date was added to that column.

I would like to change that default date to the values I am obtaining from the csv file as year, month and day. I formatted it as `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

I do not know how to get the right date in the datetime column I set as index. Note: the date must be the same because its a daily data

```
df = pd.read_csv(url,header = None, index_col = 0)

year = int(df.iloc[2][1])
month = int(df.iloc[2][2])
day = int(df.iloc[2][3])


df.index.name = None
df.drop(index= df.iloc[:7, :].index.tolist(), inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=df.columns[-1], axis = 1, inplace=True)

df.columns = ['Name Column 1','Name Column 2']
d = pd.to_datetime((datetime(year, month, day).date()), format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

[image]

Comment: did you check out [Change date of a DateTimeIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17152719/10197418)?

Comment: *however, when I put pd.to_datetime automatically a date was added to that column* - Do you mean the date part is undesirable? I could not understand whether you want to keep only `%H:%M:%S` or you also need to keep date-part.